# form_with using a nested partial renders the form contents outside of the <form></form> elements tables, rendering content into a table row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-6

> COMPLETE REPRODUCTION APP HERE:
>
> https://github.com/jasonfb/nested-forms-issue1
>
> THIS HAS BEEN SUBMITTED TO THE RAILS TEAM AS A BUG
>
> https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38919

I am seeing some strange behavior on Rails 6.0.2.2

My haml code is like this, but  I also get this result using Erb syntax.

// dashboard/skins/edit.js.erb

```
$(".skins-table tr[data-id=<%= @skin.id %>]").html("<%= j render partial: 'dashboard/skins/edit', locals: {skin: @skin} %>")
```

// dashboard/skins/_edit.haml

```
Edit
= skin.name

for
= skin.account.company_name

= form_with do |f|
  = render partial: "form",  locals: {skin: skin, f: f}
```

// dashboard/skins/_list.haml

```
Edit
= skin.name

for
= skin.account.company_name

= form_with model: skin, url: edit_dashboard_skin_path(skin) do |f|
  = render partial: "form",  locals: {skin: skin, f: f}
```

// dashboard/skins/_form.haml

```
= f.text_field :name
%label
  Skin Name


= f.text_area :header
%label
  Header


= f.text_area :footer
%label
  Footer


= f.text_area :native_scss
%label
  Native SCSS


= f.text_field :background_color
%label
  Background Color

= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Notice that the partial is rendered within the form, thus you would expect

```
<form action="/dashboard/skins/2/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
   <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="67DBVfnagSrI+DZMxfv/calLBjWq8EV2YFqMDI8oJN/ltqp1jLh3Oa64gZBRhmY25nQUsZEuFK8P/UgCLII8AA==">
   /* other form fields here */
</form>
```

However, Rails seems to be rendering ALL of the form content---including the hidden fields and any arbitrary text I stick inside of the form_with do block, as **siblings of the form, not children of the form**.

What actually happens is this:

[image]

Notice that the input elements that should be within the form aren't, they are siblings and appear below the closed form element.

What's interesting is that I see this effect only for the edit form, not for the create form, which displays correctly.

Comment: also.. it sort of doesn't matter what I put inside of `= form_with model: skin, url: edit_dashboard_skin_path(skin) do |f|`; If I remove the nested partial and just replace it with "xxxxxxxx" the xxxxxxes come out as siblings too, along with the Rails-generated hidden fields, not inside of my <form></form>

Comment: share `form` partial code in your question.

Comment: @AmitPatel-- I added some more code. I suspect the problem is related to passing it through the ERB somehow although I still can't figure out how

Comment: Actually the problem persists when I take out the HAML and just pass the form_with directly inside of the ERB. could form_with's implementation be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

My problem was that I was rendering some content into a table row `<tr>` content that was not wrapped inside of a `<td>`

never render content into a `<tr>` without wrapping that content inside of a `<td>`

this malformed content was breaking the form, making the contents come outside of the form as explained above

Answer (score 0):

For someone who faces a similar problem:

In my case, I was initially using the form_with inside a table tag

```
<table>
  .
  .
  .
  <%= form_with(url: '...') do %>
    <tbody></tbody>
  <% end %>
  .
  .
</table>
```

Moving it outside the whole table element, solved the problem.

```
<%= form_with(url: '...') do %>
  <table>
    .
    .
    .
  </table>
<% end %>
```